# How do I escape a '@' in a Dapper query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dapper

I've got a query that should contain a literal at sign (`@`). How do I express this with a Dapper query?

```
var num = cnx.Query<int>("declare @foo int = 2; select @foo").Single();
```

I've tried using literals as a workaround:

```
var num = cnx.Query<int>(
    "declare {=at}foo int = 2; select {=at}foo", new { at = "@" }
).Single();
```

But this throws a `NotSupportedException` since string literals aren't supported...

(Note that in my real code, I've got other @parameters that I actually do want replaced and auto-escaped for me, so I'd rather stick with Dapper if possible instead of just using a raw `SqlCommand`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh. I figured it out. If you have a `@param` that isn't actually bound to anything, it's passed as-is to the underlying `SqlCommand`, which passes it straight to the DB.

In other words, you don't need to do anything special to get this to work. My first example should run fine. Silly me.

Comment: actually, **all** parameters are passed down as-is (except for list expansions)... Dapper doesn't replace anything unless the curly-brace syntax is used. But yeah, your first example should work fine.

Comment: @Marc: Right, the difference is that `SqlParameter`s are generated for the others, which SQL server looks at.

Comment: well, that is no different to using a local variable in any TSQL command that may or may not also use parameters; nothing dapper-specific here